# Failed to import custom python module in Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I want to use some python modules I wrote inside Airflow (version 1.10.11), so I put all my scripts in airflow/my_scripts and exported the airflow path to PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${AIRFLOW_HOME}"
```

So the Airflow folder structure looks like this:

```
airflow/  
    |_ dag/  
    |    |_ __init__.py  
    |    |_ my_first_DAG.py  
    |_ my_scripts/
    |    |_ __init__.py         
    |    |_  custom_script.py 
    |_ __init__.py
```

Inside my_first_DAG.py I try:

```
from my_scripts import custom_script
```

But I get the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_scripts'

What could be missing?

Comment: Add `__init.py__` under `airflow` directory. That'll do, I guess.

Comment: maybe first check `PATH` in python code - maybe it uses old value without `AIRFLOW_HOME`

Comment: Did both, adding the `__ini__.py` under airflow and checking that both `PATH` are OK, still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the PYTHONPATH was only getting set in local terminal, not for all programs. FIxed by adding it in

```
~/.bashrc

~/.profile

/etc/environment
```